# How to get an array of class-names from a set of checked checkboxes using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to get an array of values from a set of checkboxes that have been checked by the end-user:

```
var array = jQuery('input:checkbox[name=items]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Instead of an array of values, I'd like to get an array of *classnames*.

My checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="vOne" class="cOne">
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="vTwo" class="cTwo">
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="vThree" class="cThree">
```

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
var array = jQuery('input:checkbox[name=items]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.class;
}).get();
```

Comment: Check the console, answer is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `this.class`, you should use:

```
this.className
```